# Force initial-scale based on viewport width

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Is there a way to force the display-zoom / initial scale for a Vue web app?

We want to do something like:

screen width <= 1460 px -> zoom100% / initial scale 1.0
screen width > 1460px -> zoom 110% / initial scale 1.1

We tried it with basic JS, but didn't work, and we didn't find any resources on this topic.

Comment: could you use a media query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries to set the css scale https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale on the document.body

Comment: What did you try? Please show us.